# How to store double values in a text file using minimum storage space?

Tags: java, file-io, storage

I am writing a simulation program that saves data to a .txt file. The data is read from the text file by another program that renders the data in the .txt file into .png images.

The way that the program stores data is as follows:

- Each new line of the text file represents a new frame of simulation
- Each line consists of information about a particle
- The information that is saved for a particle is its X coordinate, Y coordinate, and mass, all three of which are doubles.

Currently, the optimizations I've made are:

- Each double is truncated to the nearest thousandth in the file
- If a particle has collided and no longer exists, instead of writing `0.0 0.0 0.0` to the text file, `SKIP` is written.

The output of ten frames of ten particles looks like this:

```
1.314 0.69 9.806 -0.108 -0.086 12.733 -0.83 0.44 10.161 1.302 0.671 9.662 1.526 0.0010 11.814 0.383 -0.612 10.432 -0.277 -0.754 10.871 1.582 -1.072 10.06 -0.554 -0.52 10.525 -0.516 -0.663 10.757 
1.313 0.69 9.806 -0.108 -0.086 12.733 -0.83 0.439 10.161 1.303 0.67 9.662 1.526 0.0030 11.814 0.383 -0.612 10.432 -0.277 -0.754 10.871 1.581 -1.074 10.06 -0.554 -0.52 10.525 -0.515 -0.664 10.757 
1.313 0.691 9.806 -0.108 -0.086 12.733 -0.831 0.438 10.161 1.303 0.669 9.662 1.526 0.0040 11.814 0.383 -0.612 10.432 -0.277 -0.754 10.871 1.58 -1.075 10.06 -0.555 -0.52 10.525 -0.515 -0.664 10.757 
1.313 0.691 9.806 -0.108 -0.087 12.733 -0.831 0.437 10.161 1.304 0.668 9.662 1.526 0.0060 11.814 0.383 -0.612 10.432 -0.277 -0.754 10.871 1.579 -1.077 10.06 -0.555 -0.519 10.525 -0.514 -0.664 10.757 
1.313 0.691 9.806 -0.108 -0.087 12.733 -0.832 0.436 10.161 1.304 0.667 9.662 1.526 0.0080 11.814 0.383 -0.612 10.432 -0.276 -0.755 10.871 1.578 -1.078 10.06 -0.555 -0.519 10.525 -0.514 -0.665 10.757 
1.312 0.692 9.806 -0.108 -0.087 12.733 -0.832 0.435 10.161 1.305 0.666 9.662 1.526 0.0090 11.814 0.384 -0.612 10.432 -0.276 -0.755 10.871 1.577 -1.08 10.06 -0.556 -0.518 10.525 -0.514 -0.665 10.757 
1.312 0.692 9.806 -0.108 -0.087 12.733 -0.833 0.434 10.161 1.305 0.665 9.662 1.526 0.011 11.814 0.384 -0.612 10.432 -0.276 -0.755 10.871 1.576 -1.081 10.06 -0.556 -0.518 10.525 -0.513 -0.665 10.757 
1.312 0.692 9.806 -0.108 -0.087 12.733 -0.833 0.433 10.161 1.306 0.664 9.662 1.526 0.013 11.814 0.384 -0.612 10.432 -0.276 -0.755 10.871 1.575 -1.083 10.06 -0.556 -0.518 10.525 -0.513 -0.665 10.757 
1.312 0.693 9.806 -0.108 -0.087 12.733 -0.834 0.432 10.161 1.307 0.663 9.662 1.526 0.014 11.814 0.384 -0.612 10.432 -0.276 -0.755 10.871 1.574 -1.084 10.06 -0.557 -0.517 10.525 -0.512 -0.666 10.757 
1.311 0.693 9.806 -0.107 -0.087 12.733 -0.834 0.431 10.161 1.307 0.662 9.662 1.526 0.016 11.814 0.384 -0.612 10.432 -0.276 -0.755 10.871 1.572 -1.086 10.06 -0.557 -0.517 10.525 -0.512 -0.666 10.757
```

Currently, a single frame of 100000 particles takes up 1.77 MB.

Does anybody know how I should go about lowering that number?

Comment: What about file compression ?

Comment: @Berger I'm using a buffered writer to write to a single text file. Would you be able to read and write to a compressed text file without uncompressing it?

Comment: Can you make the program that creates the png images, read multiple files, i.e. somefile001.txt, somefile002.txt, etc.

Comment: @quietsamurai98 : why exactly do you need smaller files ? Network performances ? Disk space ?

Comment: @Sanj That was what I did originally, but I switched to one text file because it takes a lot of overhead time to create, open, and close .txt files. However, using multiple files still fills my SSD, so the problem is still there.

Comment: @Berger I regularly run out of disk space. The text file gets to be over 100 GB, larger than my SSD.

Comment: @quietsamurai98 A simple solution would be to use `float` instead of `double` as long as you are sure that the number does not go beyond the [`range of float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE).

Comment: You get try using a delta between the lines. i.e. if the 3rd column is repeated, rather than storing 9.806, store a single character,e.g. R, to mean the same as last line.

Comment: Store it binary instead of as text